# Why does mousing over icons in the taskbar make them disappear?

Tags: windows-10

This phenomenon has been happening to me with many Windows computers before, including my current Windows 10.

When an application closes, sometimes its logo stays as a ghost in the taskbar (in the icons to the bottom right where you click the up arrow ^). How do you make it so that the taskbar updates, so the user does not have to mouse over the icons for them to disappear?

Comment: I have not seen this. Any ghost image on the task bar would be quite obvious.   Can you be more specific about the application?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it frequently. *C'est la vie.* One could try an alternative OS.

Comment: @John its any application. for example, Malwarebytes does this. sometimes I see two Malwarebytes logos in the bottom right of my screen (often its when i close malwarebytes and restart it) so i mouse over one and it disappears. this is while malwarebytes is running

Comment: @DrMoishePippik its not a total dealbreaker for me. but it is nice to know im not going crazy and finally someone agrees they have seen this too.

Answer (score 2):

Programs have to add/remove icons from this area but Explorer owns the icon and forwards any messages to the program. If the program crashes Explorer won't know till you try to use it and it can't find the program. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicona

Comment: thank you for going so far as to provide the documentation; i appreciate it. do you know of any software that syncs it faster to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you may check below suggestion:

1. Run Winver to check current OS build number, compare it with **Windows 10 update history** -> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4555932, make sure that you have patch the OS fully with recent update.
2. Re-start system in Clean Boot, with all 3rd party process disabled, then, only open system built-in application and confirm that if problem happens again. **How to perform a clean boot in Windows:** https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows
3. Check and update hardware driver, including display driver, make sure that current driver version is compatible with the OS version.

Best Regards,
Eve Wang